# Testing Tool - Jmeter Error

Tags: java, performance, jmeter

Hello I am beginner to `jmeter`. While recording scripts, i am getting the following error. Please help me how to resolve this

```
Could not create script recoder - see log for details: >> keytool 
error:java.io.FileNotFoundException:proxyserver.jks(Access is denied)

Command failed, code 1
```

Comment: check this : https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210

Comment: any feedback on my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You are running jmeter in a folder where it does not have the rights to write.

So when JMeter starts, it tries to write in its bin folder but cannot do it.

Solution:

- Give rights to jmeter in this folder
- Move JMeter to a folder where it can write